# CSS Flexbox Inputs no responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

Im new to flexbox and css.I need some help to make this code work.
The problem is the following, i cant make the inputs, textarea and button to be responsive.
 I need them to be that width size on normal computer  page but to be smaller and responsive on mobile devices.
Any advice with help me.
Thanks a lot

```css
.email{
      padding: 0.5% 0% 0.5% 0%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      flex-flow: column;
      
    }
    
    .email >div{
      margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    }
    
    input {
      padding: 15px;
      width: 402px;
      max-width: 402px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
     
      border: 1px solid #272525;
      font-size: small;
      
    }
    ::placeholder { 
      font-size: 14px ;
      opacity: 1; 
    
    }
    
    textarea{
      padding: 15px;
      width: 402px;  
      resize: vertical;
      font-size: small;
      border: 1px solid #272525;
    }
    .button-send{
      width: 434px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-size: small;
      
    }
```

```html
<div class="email">
    <div>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email*">
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea rows="10" placeholder="Message*"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
    <button class="button-send">Send  </button>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Remove all the **fixed** pixel widths and use percentages instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the event, you need to alter CSS values exclusively for small screen sizes but retain specific values for another screen size you would then need to use media queries.

So first what is a media query?

> A media query consists of a media type and zero or more expressions that check for the conditions of particular media features.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

I'd advise reading through that document to get a better understanding of what media queries really are.

But in answer to your question to have responsive text areas you would want to add in something like this (You could also just use `max-width` by changing all your widths to 100% and setting your `max-width` to your current `width`.);

```css
.email {
  padding: 0.5% 0% 0.5% 0%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.email>div {
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

input {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 402px;
  max-width: 402px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #272525;
  font-size: small;
}

::placeholder {
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 1;
}

textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 402px;
  resize: vertical;
  font-size: small;
  border: 1px solid #272525;
}

.button-send {
  width: 434px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: small;
}

@media all and (max-width:500px) {
  textarea,.button-send,input  {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="email">
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email*">
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea rows="10" placeholder="Message*"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button-send">Send  </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add **@media querie**s in Css as I have done it for you below:-

Click on **Run code snippet** and then **Full pag**e and make your window smaller and **check** it

```css
.email {
  padding: 0.5% 0% 0.5% 0%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.email>div {
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

input {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 402px;
  max-width: 402px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #272525;
  font-size: small;
}

::placeholder {
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 1;
}

textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 402px;
  resize: vertical;
  font-size: small;
  border: 1px solid #272525;
}

.button-send {
  width: 434px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-size: small;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  input {
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
  }
  textarea {
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
  }
  button {
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="email">
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email*">
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea rows="10" placeholder="Message*"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="button-send">Send  </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```